# Compute the Var$(X_1+X_2+X_3)$ and other Variances.

Tags: probability, covariance, independence

The problem said;

Let $ X_1, X_2, X_3 $ be independent and identically distributed random variables each
with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
Below I state the work I did so far, I need help specifically in point b. If someone know how. It will be appreciated. Thanks!

> a) Find Var$(3X_1) $.

Then Var$(3X_1)=\;9\text{Var}$$(X_1)=9\cdot1=9$

> (b) Find Var$(X_1 + X_2 + X_3)$.

> Var$(X_1)+$Var$(X_2)+$Var$(X_3)=3$

> (c) Find Cov$(X_1 + X_2,X_2 + X_3)$.
>
> Cov$(X_1+X_2, X_2+X_3) = \;$Cov$(X_1, X_2+X_3) + $Cov$(X_2,X_2+X_3)= \;$Cov$(X_2, X_2+X_3)=\;$Cov$(X_2,X_2)+$Cov$(X_2,X_3)=\;$Cov$(X_2,X_2)=\;$Var$(X_2)=1$

Looks simple and I'm worried if I miss some key step.
Thanks.

Comment: because they're independent, $Var(X_1 + X_2 + X_3) = Var(X_1) + Var(X_2) + Var(X_3)$

Comment: Now it is right.

Comment: Is it right point c also?